# How to modify BoardColumn field of a Work Item using REST API

Tags: tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

I have a customized Board with:

- First default column "New" mapped to "New" state.
- Second column "To do" also mapped to "New" state (After weekly reviewing new WI, team moves them in this column to avoid reviewing them next time).

In the TFS Board I can move a WI from the First Column to the second columun.

With the REST API when I read an existing WI, I got the right information for the BoardColumn field.

But when I used the REST API to modify BoardColumn it raises an exception.

I have the bypass rules permission.

```
 $tfsTargetUri = "https://path to my collection/"
 $tfsTargetProject = "MyProject"
 $MyWI = 56 #use an existing Id
 $mycredentials = Get-Credential

 $workitem2 =
 @(
 @{op="test";path="/rev";value="1"},
 @{op="add";path="/fields/System.BoardColumn";value="New"}
 #@{op="add";path="/fields/System.State";value="Active"}
 )

 $json2 = $workitem2 | ConvertTo-Json  -Depth 100
 $url2= $tfsTargetUri + $tfsTargetProject + '/_apis/wit/workitems/' + $MyWI +'?bypassRules=true&api-version=2.0'
 $targetbug = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url2 -Method Patch -Credential $mycredentials -Body ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($json2)) -ContentType 'application/json-patch+json'
```

When I try with BoardColumn in workitem2 it raises an exception.

When I modify the comment in workitem2 to change the State field, this is working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The field `System.BoardColumn` is read only by design, is not a regular work item rule, so `bypass = true` can helps in this case. This is the reason why you can not update this field with the regular way.

According to new [Microsoft Docs](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Samples/WorkItemTracking/WorkItemsSample.cs) you provided (the relevant section added 3 days ago) there is a solution. You can update the field if you update another field value - if you get the work item and investigate the fields you will see this kind of field:

```
WEF_432678B52358ACDA34ASDA243489FD343_Kanban.Column
```

When you update this field to the Board Column State the work item will move to this Board Column.

Example how to extract this field from work item details:

```
$url = $collection/_apis/wit/workitems/$id?api-version=4.0
$workItem = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get ...
$boardColumnField = $workItem.fields.PSObject.Properties.Name.Where({$_.Contains("Kanban")})[0]

# Now in the work item json use it: /fields/$boardColumnFied
```

Comment: Yes, but CreatedBy is also read only and it is possible to modify this field using REST API and bypass rule.

Comment: And looking this code, it seems to work: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Samples/WorkItemTracking/WorkItemsSample.cs

Comment: @Dominique you are right! it works! did you success to do it in PowerShell?

Comment: @Dominique this section on the docs added 3 days ago! I updated my answer :)

Comment: Hello ShaykySorry, first of all sorry for my late answer. Yes, it works now. Fits tips to check: if you want to change the Board Column of a Bug, in Board setting "Bugs are managed with requirements." otherwise the Kanban field doesn't exist. Thanks for your code to extract the BoardColumnField from the workitem object.

Comment: @Dominique thanks for the tip!! you're welcome about the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here are the settings that worked for me when using Postman:

[image]

[image]